# How to accept additional arguments for an option in tools.cli?

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I'm a Clojure newbie.

I need multiple arguments for option `-a` of my cli app, like:

```
java -jar app.jar -a 12 abc xyz
```

First one is a number, and other two have to be strings.

My code is:

```
["-a" "--add LINE TYPE ENTRY" "Add entry to specified line number of the menu"
:parse-fn #(split % #" ")
:validate [#(number? (Integer/parseInt (first %))) "ERROR: Invalid position"]
```

But I observed the `%` passed to `:parse-fn` function to be a vector containing only the first argument, i.e., `[12]`

the other arguments are listed as value of the key `:arguments` of the map returned by `parse-opts`

Now, 
(1) Is there a way to validate those unprocessed arguments? 
(2) How will I retrieve and use those arguments?

Comment: I have not seen this done.  You could go the route of passing this in one argument (e.g. `java ... -a "12 abc xyz"` (maybe even use a better separator than ` ` like e.g. `:` or `/`)) -- or pass that with three arguments (e.g. `-[lte]`) -- or just dont use tools.cli at all, pick the first argument as a "command" from allowed ones and apply the rest of the args to it.  From a plain user persective i find this even odd.  No unix CLI comes into my mind, that has multiple arguments to a single-letter option.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot parse white-space separated values for one option at a time.
Normally you would do it like this: `-a opt1 -a opt2 -a opt3`, but since you have a different type for `opt1` this will not work.

What about separating them by comma?

```
(require '[clojure.tools.cli :refer [parse-opts]])

(def cli-opts
  [["-a" "--add LINE TYPE ENTRY" "Add entry to specified line number of the menu"
    :parse-fn (fn [a-args]
                (-> a-args
                    (str/split #",")
                    (update 0 #(Integer/parseInt %))))
    :validate [(fn [[num s1 s2]]
                 (and (number? num)
                      (string? s1)
                      (string? s2)))]]])

(parse-opts ["-a" "12,abc,xyz"] cli-opts)

;;=> {:options {:add [12 "abc" "xyz"]}, :arguments [], :summary "  -a, --add LINE TYPE ENTRY  Add entry to specified line number of the menu", :errors nil}
```

Another option would be to introduce two or three different options for `a`: `--line`, `--type` and `--entry`.

Comment: Well a single string with comma delimiter seems a good choice... it wont interfere with names and numbers in anyways. Thank you, I'll try it.